# Running apt-get error

Tags: apt

I am on a Mac Pro version 10.6.8, and I believe the environment is Ubuntu. I am trying to use the `apt-get` command but keep getting this `E: Couldn't find package` error. I tried downloading fink to solve the issue, but haven't had any luck. I also checked the `$PATH` and it seemed to be correct. Not too familiar with Linux/Unix so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Finally, you can run

```
 sudo apt-get install *packagename*
```

Make sure you are connected to the Internet first.